# Debugging in Xcode

Tags: xcode, debugging

I am just getting into Cocoa at the moment. I have set up Xcode to show the Console and Debugger when debugging. However, when I have killed the app Xcode does not return to the project view. It stays in the Debug view, showing the debugger and console.

Is there any way I can get it to automatically return to Project view? Sorry, I may not be using the right lingo here but I hope you guys understand what I'm saying.

Cheers,
Dany.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to get it to automatically return after killing the app, but Cmd-0 will return you to the main  project management view, whatever that's called.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't close it, use Exposé (F10 or Fn + F10 on your keyboard) to bring to visibility all of Xcode's window (it actually works for all applications). Otherwise, Cmd + 0 will also bring it to front.